# Definition of Leitzanus

Tags: words, hebrew, middos-character-traits

I have often seen *leitzanus*, mockery, defined along the lines of making a joke out of serious matters. Intuitively this is a good definition, but does anyone have a source which spells it out?

And to add to the question I heard a shiur on YUTorah.org where *leitzanus* is defined as treating a trivial matter as important in addition to making light of the serious, but no the source for this definition was given.

Comment: Sharrie Teshuvah and Mesilas Yesharim talk about how terrible it is but don't define it.

Comment: as does the Tanya

Comment: Yirmeyahu, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: ANother possible translation is "cynicism."

Comment: Try [Avot 3:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h49.htm)

Comment: @SimchasTorah - And Sefer Tehillim and Masechet Avot...

Answer (score 5):

It is in Maharal:
 [ספר נתיבות עולם ב - נתיב הליצנות - פרק ב](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11804&hilite=c04dfb08-1d52-46f1-b082-c160e6b2cfbb&st=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91+%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA&pgnum=241) 
הלצנות הוא הפך הדין כי הלצנות הוא דבר התול
"... Leitzanus is the opposite of "Din" in that Leitzanus is the concept of mockery..."

(Unfortunately Chelek Beis of the relatively newer print of Maharal is not yet available)

There is other material there and in the previous perek which builds a strong case for the definition you have proposed.

Rav Hutner, in Pachad Yitzchak on Purim, Maamer Alef, explains it the way you are saying and bases much of his thesis on a statement of Rabbeinu Yona. He adds that the only Leitzanus that is ever permitted is when its purpose is to restore honor to that which it is fitting.

Comment: I believe the new printing you referred to can be found here, http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14209&st=&pgnum=222, but I cannot find the exact loshon.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu It's on [the next page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14209&pgnum=221)( though HebrewBooks mixed the pages up and put it as the page before the one you linked to), right column, 8th-9th lines from the top.

Answer (score 4):

Orchos Tzadikkim, at the end of Shaar Hashtika, has a quite extensive explanation about the various types of Leitzanus. See [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94#.5B.D7.A2.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.9C.D7.99.D7.A6.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.AA.5D).

Comment: Can you provide a summary?

Comment: Here is an English translation: http://books.google.com/books?id=nxCyxmZCnUMC&lpg=PP12&dq=orchos%20tzaddikim%20translation&pg=PA373#v=onepage&q=orchos%20tzaddikim%20translation&f=false

Comment: (the missing pages there are just the Hebrew text.)

Comment: @Yirmeyahu - the above was meant for you.