# What's wrong Letzanut?

Tags: reward-punishment, middos-character-traits, olam-haba-world-to-come, tractate-sotah

The Talmud in Sotah 42 says four groups do not receive the Shechina (divine presence) in the next world. One of these is the group of "letzim" (jesters).

What is considered bad letzanut? I assume some form of joking is permitted and emotionally beneficial to humans. Where does one draw the line in this?

Comment: there might be a difference between leitzim and baduchim from Taanit 22a (18 thick lines down). The latter are praiseworthy. The issue seems to be one of translation.

Comment: @Danno you mean letzanut does not mean jokingas one of its meanings?

Comment: I mean that the conclusion you draw in general might only apply to a particular subset as called forth by "leitzan" -- badchan, also sometimes translated as "jester" is ben olam haba.

Comment: Latzans are those who scoff at holy things. Imagine an inspiring chazan on yom kippur. He sings some very spiritual cantorial stuff but when he bends down in alenu, a Latzan males a fart sound. The chazzan's bending is ridiculed and the holy singing contrasting to the undignified flatulence adds to the comedy but becomes a joke to the congregants and loses its spiritual punch.

Comment: I don't think it's any coincidence that the 1st Tehilim (psalms) says that it is praiseworthy when a person has not sat among the sitting places of *letzim* - scoffers. Those that scoff deny a person's integrity, behavior, and in a large sense, laugh at their existence. It's a most despicable behavior. King David knew what he was saying :-)

Comment: @ClintEastwood what about pirkei avot "two who sit together and dont study torah is a moshav letzim?"

Comment: @ray What about it?

Comment: `taamei-mitzvot-reasons` seems inappropriate, as we are not discussing a mitsvah.

Comment: @Clint Eastwood - "undignified flatulence"?  Any examples of "dignified flatulence" ..um.. floating around?

Comment: If it is, I haven't smelled it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pele yoets](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=219&t=&Search=) seems to expain what the bad one is

> The definition of mockery is that a person mocks his friend in
>   order to increase laughter and levity

Comment: interesting.+1 but he brings the mishna which says "two who sit together and dont say divrei torah is a moshav letzim". how is that mockery to increase laughter?

Comment: @ray thank you, I did not understand your question

Comment: the pele yoets above brings the mishna in pirkei avot: "two who sit together and don't say divrei torah - this is a moshav letzim". I assume he means something other than mockery to increase laughter right?

Comment: @ray I saw it differently, I saw it that eather usually when 2 board people are eating together, the conversion will lead to mockery. Or that the meal itself is mocking (maybe Hashem) if there is no Torah. I do not see anything about laughter

Comment: Any thoughts on the comparison/contrast with the definition of leitzanus discussed here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/678/899 ?